# Successful cyclists with facial hair

Tags: body-hair

It's not common to see a professional cyclist with facial hair - moustache or beard.

Simon Geschke winning a stage in Trour de France in 2015 and Bradley Wiggins are the only examples of bearded winners I can think of.

Were there cyclists in the past that reached the top while avoiding the razor?

Comment: To much wind resistance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I fail to see how knowing the answer benefits the community. refer http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @mattnz It's not really constructive to share the link link to 'the law'. It would be better to point the element that my question violates. I looked and I cannot find any.

Comment: Try asking on http://sports.stackexchange.com   That's much more about the competition.  Here we're more about the mechanics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://sports.stackexchange.com   would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Marco Pantani is pretty famous.

Comment: Beard or no beard makes no difference http://www.bikeradar.com/road/news/article/specialized-test-aerodynamics-of-a-beard-video-41144/

Comment: @mayu "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers"; "there is no actual problem to be solved".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reality, you only lose less than a watt of power with facial hair. Which over a 40 km time trial is less than 1 second.

Specialized did a wind tunnel experiment: